# Multi-parameterized SQL syntax invalid using WHERE AND

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Below is the code in my model, I'm using Codeigniter, I'm sure there's a simple problem with it but I've been trying for a long time, any ideas?

```
<?php
    class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function checkLogin($username, $pass) {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=? AND password=?;";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $username, sha1($pass));

        if ($query -> num_rows() == 1) {
            return True;
        } else {
            return False;
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND password=?' at line 1

Comment: Can you be more precise about the problem you have ? What PHP error do you see ?

Comment: Sure, see edit @lovasoa

Comment: Although it won't solve the problem, why not do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=? AND password=?;`?

Comment: What is the type of your $this->db object ?

Comment: That would make more sense yes!

Comment: We can't answer this question without knowing what `$this->db->query()` does. It apparently is *not* doing a prepare & execute.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using PDO, I'm using Codeigniter frameworks if that helps @AndrewMorton

Comment: I think there is typing mistake at
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=? AND password=?;";
it should be 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=? AND password=?";

Answer (score 2):

If `$this->db` is a [PDO object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), than [its `query` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) doesn't allow you to use argument binding.

You will have to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). Your code would then look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Users WHERE username=:user AND password=:pass";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':user' => $username, ':pass' => sha1($pass)));
$count = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 'count');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, using named parameter placeholders is not mandatory in PDO. You can use positional parameters (`?` placeholders). But you cannot use both styles in the same SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found that the below worked, the parameters for the SQL statement just needed to be in a array.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($username, sha1($pass)));
```